# How to read/write a register via modbus TCP

Tags: tcp, modbus

I'm very new to modbus and I need to know how to read and write from/to a register via tcp.
Can someone post a tcp message example to read and one to write to a register?
Code in C/C++ or Golang would be appreciated but it doesn't have to be, just the string with the message would be fine.

Comment: Modbus communication needs more than a single message. You should review the specifications on the Modbus Specifications and Implementation guides at http://www.modbus.org/specs.php and the numerous open source implementations to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org).  It's a cross-platform library under LGPL with support for Modbus TCP and RTU.